# MULTIPLE COUNTS IN THE SAME QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, window-functions

I have this table, i want to count the  number of orders which are of the same type , and the count of all orders, as follow

```
ord_id type  
1      A
2      B
3      A
4      C
```

Here is the result :

```
TYPE COUNT  TOTAL
A    2      4
B    1      4
C    1      4
```

where count column is the count of orders based on their type, and total is the total orders.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*)
FROM  
  table
where type = 'A'

Union

SELECT type, COUNT(*)
FROM  
  table
where type = 'b';
```

Comment: Skip the UNION, do a GROUP BY!

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and window functions:

```
select 
    type,
    count(*) cnt,
    sum(count(*)) over() total
from mytable
group by type
```